# How do I move a folder I created in my drive to ONLY a shared folder?

Tags: google-drive

I have a large amount of folders that I created in My Drive, however these are also organized in another shared folder.  I no longer need these folders in My Drive specifically as long as I can find them in the shared folder.

How do I move them so they are not cluttering up my personal drive but I can still find them in a shared folder if I need to?

Comment: You're trying to get these folders to not display when you're looking at the top-level "My Drive"? Or something else?

Comment: Hi there, so my Drive has 3 "Main Folders" that are shared folders which I access often and want to keep shared to My Drive.  The remaining 8 or so folders are subfolders of one of the Main folders.  I believe the majority of them were created by me which is why they are showing in My Drive.  However, I would prefer to just find them in the main folder as needed instead of seeing them in My Drive.  If I say I want them removed, will they still exist in the shared main folder?

Comment: Maybe this isn't even an option...not sure

Comment: Are you sure the folders in the root of your drive aren't just  duplicates of the ones in the subfolder? You should be able to see if the ones in the shared folder have been updated more recently.

Comment: They may be duplicates, you are right.  If the ones in the shared folder have indeed been updated more recently, will that be my best indication that they are duplicates?

Comment: since you have the particualr folder in the drive  already organised in the shared folder so you can remove the folder from  the drive by right clicking on the folder and then choose the option to remove if you want to delete it

Answer (score 1):

Somebody has to (I believe) "own" the folder even if it was shared.

So if you are the original owner of the folder and *then* shared it, unfortunately I don't think you can

One solution I had to a similar issue is I signed up for a new Google Apps account (back when they were free - I am sure a regular GMail account will do just fine) and then shared the folders with that user.

I then created a new folder with my dummy GMail account, and created a similar folder structure in that account, and copied all the files there.  It was fast and I think it basically didn't actually copy the files.

I then (held my breath....) and deleted the original folder from my normal GMail account and shared the folder with myself from the dummy account.

It's a bit of an odd solution, but I think the reason is Google wants to make sure there is someone whose account has the files and folders associated with it